# Creating list based on pandas data frame conditions - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, if-statement

I have a table:

| Player | Team | GS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | A | NaN |
| John | B | 1 |
| Mike | A | 1 |
| James | A | 1 |

And would like to make 2 separate lists (TeamA & TeamB) so that they players are split by team and also filters so that the players that have a '1' in GS are only part of the list.  The final lists would look like:

```
TeamA = Mike, James
TeamB = John
```

In this case, Jack was excluded from the TeamA list because he did not have a 1 value in the GS column.

Any direction would help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
out = (df.loc[df['GS'].eq(1)]                  # filter rows
         .groupby('Team')['Player'].agg(list)  # aggregate as lists
         .to_dict()                            # convert to dict
      )
```

output:

```
{'A': ['Mike', 'James'], 'B': ['John']}
```

Comment: How could I split these into individual lists once I get them in a dictionary.  I essentially just want two lists of players by team.

Comment: @BenjaminBlackburn: `TeamA = out['A'] ; TeamB = out['B']`, but honestly I don't see the point, just use the dictionary ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as "filtering" the data based on certain conditions.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(...)

# Create a mask that will be used to select team A rows
mask_team_a = dataframe['Team'] == 'A'
# Create a second mask for the GS filter
mask_gs = dataframe['GS'] == 1

# Use the .loc accessor to get the rows by combining masks with '&'
team_a_df = dataframe.loc[mask_team_a & mask_gs, :]
# You can use the same masks, but use the '~' to say 'not team A'
team_b_df = dataframe.loc[(~mask_team_a) & mask_gs, :]

team_a_list = list(team_a_df['Player'])
team_b_list = list(team_b_df['Player'])
```

This might be a bit verbose, but it allows for the most flexibility in the future if you need to tweak your selections.